# Trying to add conditions to controller .find method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Having a few issues starting out with rails.

I'm creating a directory, initially, all additions will be displayed as approved false until I manually approve them.

I'm creating the admin interface where I can click 'Approve' so I need to display all listings with attribute of approved = false.

Here's the code:

```
  def listings
    @listings = Listing.find(:all, :conditions => "approved = false")
  end
```

And here's the error

```
Couldn't find all Listings with 'id': (all, {:conditions=>"approved = false"}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)
```

A little help would be brilliant, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are using a very old `find` syntax (Rails 2.0).

The newer syntax no longer uses :all, and no longer passes conditions to the `find` method. Assuming you are using Rails 4, the equivalent is

```
def listings
  @listings = Listing.where(approved: false)
end
```

You can use `.all`, but it's just syntactic sugar in this case.

```
def listings
  @listings = Listing.where(approved: false).all
end
```

Comment: Thanks mate, really appreciate your help. Additionally, the table entry seems to be displaying in its entirety instead of displaying just the fullname as the view states using listing.fullname - Any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 1):

You try to use syntax from Rails 2.x. You should do:

```
@listings = Listing.where(approved: false)
```